# Running Node.js project alongside a Laravel project on CentOS server - Conflict with default route

Tags: node.js, laravel, apache, centos7, httpd.conf

I have a CentOS server running a Laravel project as the default route (home) using Apache. Now, I need to deploy a separate Node.js project on the same server, but I'm encountering conflicts with the existing Laravel project's default route.

Here's the current setup:

CentOS CentOS v7.9.2009 STANDARD virtuozzo

Apache web server serving the Laravel project as the default route (http://example.com/)
The Laravel project is accessible at the root URL (http://example.com/)
The Node.js project resides in a subdirectory, e.g., "/nodejs-project"
Both projects work individually, but when I try to access the Node.js project, it's being intercepted by Laravel's default route, leading to unexpected behavior.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Installed Node.js and verified that the Node.js project works correctly when accessed directly via its URL (http://my_ipaddress:port).
Configured the Apache virtual host for the Node.js project with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/nodejs-project
   <Directory /var/www/html/nodejs-project>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, even with this setup, accessing the Node.js project at http://example.com/nodejs-project still triggers the Laravel default route.

My main question is: How can I properly configure Apache or the Node.js project to ensure that the Laravel project's default route doesn't intercept requests to the Node.js project?

Additionally, I have considered using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Node.js, but I'm unsure about the necessary configuration in this scenario. If Nginx is a better option, please provide guidance on how to set it up correctly with both the Laravel and Node.js projects.

Any help or suggestions on resolving this conflict and achieving successful coexistence of the Laravel and Node.js projects would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!